# GeoServer use GeoPackage on read only file system

Tags: geoserver, geopackage

I'm trying to use a .gpkg file, which is on a NAS, and the GeoServer user has only read access to this file system.

Trying to add the datasource to GeoServer gives the following error:

```
Error creating data store, check the parameters. Error message: Unable to 
obtain connection: batch entry 1: [SQLITE_READONLY] Attempt to write a 
readonly database (attempt to write a readonly database)
```

Is there a way that GeoServer can use a GeoPackage file which is located on a read-only file system?

Comment: Looks like the read only option for GeoPackage datasoruce connections has been added in a later version.  I'm using Geoserver 2.18.3. https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/_images/connection.png

Comment: That's 2 years old, please do update it is free

Comment: True, but I have limited ability to modify the production servers that's currently running GeoServer.  Hopefully I can get it upgraded in the next year.

Comment: It may also be necessary to set the gpkg database to use journal mode DELETE instead of WAL https://sqlite.org/forum/info/8debe446d2b5dbe3.